# Android Instant Apps launch programmatically

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am new to Android instant app. I like to know if any 3rd party app which supports Instant app, then how can I open that in my app programmatically.

I like to build something like this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roidtechnologies.appbrowzer

It has many apps which are supported instant apps. So I can access it.

Answer (score 4):

App that you referred to (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roidtechnologies.appbrowzer) doesn’t actually open instant apps, it opens the websites instead.

Instant Apps are meant to be opened via a URL. You can browse some existing instant apps with these example URLs by opening the link via Gmail, Hangouts, etc (requires you to first enable Instant Apps https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211):

- https://www.yummly.com/recipes
- https://www.skyscanner.net/flights-from/lond/cheap-flights-from-london.html
- https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty

In addition to the link provided by Rasoul Miri, you can also check out this 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#0

It’s a great practice tutorial that demonstrates how to convert your non-AIA project into one that includes the instant app.

Answer (score 0):

Android Instant Apps enables native Android applications to run in response to launching a URL, without installing the app. Instant apps can use many Android APIs and you use Android Studio to build them.
check this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html)